# Debian 7 - Kernel Panic after libc6 update

Tags: debian, kernel-panic

I installed and configured Debian 7.2 Wheezy AMD64 few days ago, I spent days configuring everything out and installing useful apps etc, so finally I tried to install Wine.

And what happened?
Dependency problem - libc6 is version 2.13 but it should be 2.17 to satisfy Wine. 
Unfortunately, there is no stable version available so I used sid to install libc6 2.17.
It got installed, but, after finishing installation, all commands stopped working.
I was unable to call any command, it just reports that command is NOT found.
I thought that reboot may fix the problem, so I done hard-reboot and after GRUB menu it stucks:

```
switch_root can't execute '/sbin/init' no such file or directory
Kernel Panic - not syncing
```

And my Debian is now is in unusable state. I have Dual Boot with Windows 7 64-bit.
I also have Debian 7.2 Wheezy AMD64 live on USB flash so I can use it for repair.

I do not have enough experience with Debian based distros to solve this. Can someone give me step-by-step guide?

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but how did you install Wine? I think it's weird it wouldn't work with the libc provided... As for the solution, normally I would advice chrooting into the installation with a liveCD, but I think you'll be getting the same error. You could try to copy all /lic/libc files from the live environment into the new system, and once you have it running, reinstall the proper libc.

Comment: I tried to install latest version of Wine, not one from the repository.

Comment: If you need to run a _modern_ version of wine, it's probably best to do so on a distribution which already provides the necessary dependencies. Mixing and matching from different Debian versions is generally a recipe for disaster and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: The thing is that this method is worked on Debian 7 Wheezy x86....
So I didn't expected problems like this.

Comment: It will take some serious Linux chops to recover the Debian system so it works again (copying over a bunch of /lib/ files from a rescue CD to the broken system, removing cached ld files by hand, etc.) Is there any important data that would be lost if you reinstall?

Comment: I can backup all data, but I customized it and I will not like to start from begin.... :/

Comment: I say this ad nauseum, but backporting a newer version of Wine is probably possible. Upgrading libc6 as you have done, is, of course, a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To repair libc6, start your Debian-based rescue system from the USB flash, mount your broken system partition and prepare a chroot environment using

```
mount --bind /proc MOUNTPATH/proc 
mount --rbind /dev MOUNTPATH/dev
mount --bind /sys MOUNTPATH/sys
```

Download the `libc6` 2.13-38 package for your architecture (probably amd64) from http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libc6 and install it using `dpkg -root=MOUNTPATH PATH_TO_DEBFILE`. Probably you need to add some `--force-` flags. See the [man page of `dpkg`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%207.0%20wheezy&format=html&locale=en) for details. If this does not work, you can extract files using `dpkg-deb -X` and then copy it to the correct folder and run `ldconfig -r MOUNTPATH`.

After this you should be able to chroot to `MOUNTPATH` and run `update-initramfs -u` to update your initrd. Now your system should boot again. The package dependencies are probably still broken and need to be fixed by uninstalling/downgrading packages.